# Tensorflow loading unlabeled local data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Let's say, I am training an autoencoder (so I need to define the input dataset, and also the target output). And I need a dataset that's just images (no labels).

I've tried using `flow_from_directory()`, but it assigns a class to the dataset, and when passed into training, it will collide with the target data, producing an error.

So I guess what I need is to convert my local images into a dataset with a structure like `tensorflow_datasets.mnist`.

## Folder structure:

```
/data
  /low
    -0.png
    -1.png
    -...
  /high
    -0.png
    -1.png
    -...
```

## What I've tried:

```
low_generator = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1/255.0,
    validation_split=0.2
)

# when path is directly to the image folder - no images found
# when path is to parent folder, specifying which folder to use - it assigns labels too
train_low_iterator = low_generator.flow_from_directory(
    # 'path to parent directory'
    'path to directory',
    target_size=(480, 270),
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode='input',
    subset='training',
    # add this when path is to parent
    # classes=['low']
)

validation_low_iterator = low_generator.flow_from_directory(
    'same as above',
    target_size=(480, 270),
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode='input',
    subset='validation',
    # same as above
    classes=['low']
)

# analogic to above
high_generator
train_high_iterator
validation_high_iterator
```

## Class_mode `None`

Source code says, that if `None` is used as `class_mode`, it won't be yielding the labels. [Source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.6.0/keras/preprocessing/image.py#:%7E:text=class_mode%3A%20Mode%20for,of%20a%20batch)

But neither of these examples worked (same issue as before, either nothing is found, or it's yielding labels again:

```
iterator = generator.flow_from_directory(
    'parent_path',
    class_mode=None,
    classes=['something']
)
iterator = generator.flow_from_directory(
    'parent_path',
    classes=['something']
)
iterator = generator.flow_from_directory(
    'direct_path',
    class_mode=None
)
iterator = generator.flow_from_directory(
    'direct_path'
)
```

### I've also tried `image_dataset_from_directory()`

```
train_low_dataset = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    'path/low',
    labels = None,
    label_mode = None,
    color_mode = 'rgb',
    batch_size = 32,
    image_size = (480, 270),
    shuffle = False,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = 'training'
)
```

This is able to load all the data, return a dataset, but it throws an error (at train start):

`raise ValueError("'y' argument is not supported when using " ValueError: 'y' argument is not supported when using python generator as input.`

Which I'm not able to resolve right now (since I need to use both input and output data, and both train and validation).

## Training

```
model.fit(
    train_low_iterator, train_high_iterator,
    epochs=15,
    batch_size=8,
    shuffle=True,
    validation_data=(validation_low_iterator, validation_high_iterator)
)
```

Comment: flow_from_directory has a parameter class_mode. If you set class_mode='input' then the label is the same as the input image. It is specifically intended for use with autoencoders

Comment: I've tried that one. If I set it directly to the folder with images, it doesn't find anything, and if I set it to the parent folder, it again assigns a class. I'll include the code example in question.

Comment: @GerryP Just checked the source code, and it says, if I use None, it doesn't yield the labels. Tried that, same result (Updating question once again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create a custom generator function (a fancy `for` loop with `yield` at the end), but unsuccessfully (I'll retry in the future, and will update this answer if I get it properly working).

Figured it out: [so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239474/tensorflow-variable-image-input-size-autoencoder-upscaling/70239475#70239475)

However what worked, was a generator object converted into a `numpy array`.

#### Folder structure is the same as in the question.

## Creating iterator

```
low = np.array([cv2.imread(f.path) / 255 for f in os.scandir("/data/low")])
high = np.array([cv2.imread(f.path) / 255 for f in os.scandir("/data/high")])

train_low = low[:205]
validate_low = low[205:]
train_high = high[:205]
validate_out = high[205:]
```

## Training

```
model.fit(x=train_low, y=train_high,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=True,
    validation_data=(validate_low, validate_high),
)
```