# How does tf.keras.util.array_to_image() work with regards to memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I have image data that I want to use in a TensorFlow model, but I have to retrieve the image as an (Numpy) array of pixel values. From what I've read, TensorFlow has to read an image in as some image format and from some location. I know that `tf.keras.util.array_to_image()` can convert an array to a PIL instance of an image, and I know that there are several other libraries that have similar functionality, such as `PIL.Image.fromarray()`.

My problem is that I don't want to duplicate the image data by copying it to a new format. The API documentation for the `tf.keras.util.array_to_image()` says that it returns a "PIL image instance". Does that mean that it is copying all array values to a new data structure and returning that, or is it creating an image data structure that references the original array pixel values?

As a follow-up question, if the keras method does duplicate the data (by having both the original array and the image instance have independent values), is there a way to have TensorFlow accept an array representation of an image without needing to duplicate it as a separate image file?

Comment: you can feed numpy arrays into keras model directly

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh By this, do you mean that I can feed a numpy array representation of an image into a TF model directly? As in, something like 'model.evaluate(my_nparray)' ?

Comment: yes, indeed. I've been working on something like this myself, because I wanted to load local images into a model, but couldn't find a good way, but I figured it out in the end: [Tensorflow loading local unlabeled data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69668819/tensorflow-loading-unlabeled-local-data)

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh I read over your linked post, and I'm not sure if what I'm talking about is the same concept. It seems that you had some directory structure of image files, and read them into one or more nparrays. Then, evaluate parses through the array to the indexed image object. For me, a single image retrieved as a nparray of pixel values, not as an image instance. If I tried to feed that into the evaluate function, would tf be able to recognize the whole nparray as a single image?

Comment: If you're passing an image as `(1, height, width, channels)`, Tensorflow will recognize it as a single image

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the same issue. You might run into a problem, that your model only accepts image sequences, in that case, just convert your single image into what Nicolas suggested, or encapsulate it in an array, and it will then be accepted. You just have to make sure it matches up.